# nginx: Deny all files inside directory

Tags: security, nginx, download, server

I have an "upload" directory where users can upload confidential files (jpg, png, pdf). Each user gets assigned a folder inside upload, ex: /001/, /002/, ..., /999/, etc.

I want these files to be accessible only through SFTP, so the url http://example.com/upload/259/image.jpg should return a 403 error message.

I tried many variations, but still the files can be accessed through the url.

```
location ~ /upload/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
    deny all;
    return 403;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to match that part: '/259/image'

This should work:

```
location ~ /upload/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$ {
   deny all;
   return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If access to /upload is *only* via sftp, then this is all you should need:

```
location ^~ /download/ {return 403;}
```

By skipping the regex cycle with ^~ you'll improve performance. Also your configuration will scale with fewer problems by not using a regex location. A prefix location can go anywhere, but not a regex location. The first regex match will be used which can lead to confusion down the road.

Comment: Thanks for your solution putnamhill, it also works. If you have two minutes, the requirements changed and I have a new related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932619/nginxphp-redirect-protected-file-request-to-php-script-and-then-download-the-f